# How to refresh or reload component in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently working in angular 2. here i am facing a interesting problem. i have a search bar in my header which redirects me to "**resultsComponent**". In **resultsComponent** it shows me search results. but when i am standing in **resultsComponent** and want to search something else. when i enter something to search in search bar, it does not redirect me because i am already on that component. due to which **resultsComponent**'s constructor does not hit again. and i can not get query value because i am getting query value in constructor. how can i reload this constructor. here is my code samples.
**HeaderSearch**

```
<input type="search" name=query [(ngModel)]="query" #quer="ngModel" class="form-control"  class="form-control" required>
                                <button type="submit"(click)="Search()"  class="btn">
                                    <i class="icon icon-header-search"></i>
                                </button>
```

and **.ts**

```
Search(){
//  alert(this.query)
//console.log(this.query);
        localStorage.setItem('val',JSON.stringify(this.query));
this.router.navigate(['/result']);

      }
```

and **result.ts**

```
constructor() { 
  this.query=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('val'));
  }

 this.httpService.searchGeneric(this.query,1).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.Getspecs = data;
    this.count=data['totalItems'];
      }
    );
```

when i am standing on results component. can any body tell how my search can still work and update my results component whenever i search it again. any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with starting point. 
In your header search component define viewchild for result component.
In the result componant define a method which will do the all the stuff you are doing in constructor , just keep the dependency injectiom in constructor.

Now on hitting search button , search method will be called in header search componant , in this method using viewchild object call the result component method and everything will be refreshed. Below is some sample code:

**Search Component :**

```
@ViewChild(ResultsComponent) resultsComponent: ResultsComponent;

Search(){
   //  alert(this.query)
  //console.log(this.query);
  localStorage.setItem('val',JSON.stringify(this.query));
  this.router.navigate(['/result']);
  resultsComponent.open();
}
```

**Result Component:**

```
constructor() { 
}

open() {
  this.query=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('val'));
  this.httpService.searchGeneric(this.query,1).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.Getspecs = data;
  this.count=data['totalItems'];
    }
  );   
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to keep dependency in constructor? with simple example?

Comment: In your code I dont see need of dependency injection as of now , however if you need to see what is it and how it works , you can refer angular io document https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: ok. somehow i have called the function from header. it is updating my data set but not updating my DOM? can you have any idea?

Comment: Can you share your DOM for result component , which is not been updated.